# Get value from Array's value of Object's key from httpheader JAVA

Tags: java, object, cookies, http-headers, arrayobject

```
{cookie=[abc=val1;apu-s={"comp":true,"approval":false};],xyz=val2}
```

I need to get the value of approval flag, ie., False.

After getting the value I need to pass it to a setter method.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking and I don't see any tries on your end yet. So `headers.getHeaderString("cookie")` should return the string `[abc=val1;apu-s={"comp":true,"approval":false};],xyz=val2` which you'd then need to parse. Did you try that already?

Comment: No kindly tell me how to do.. question is just get approval flag's value through get methods.. I tired getting from many inbuilt methods from java but was unable to get it. This {} which I represented above is a cookie from headers.

Comment: You can also provide it by parsing it into JSON object

Comment: You could start using [`HttpCookie.parse(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/net/HttpCookie.html#parse(java.lang.String)). Then you'd probably have to parse the JSON string you get from `getValue()` using a JSON library of your choice, e.g. Jackson or Gson.